# Incorporate setTimeout Into jQuery .each

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code requests json data from a URL.  Once it has that data, it runs an .each function for each element in the json data.  For examples sake, I have reduced the .each function to simply doing a document.write with each value from the json and alerting "finished" after it is over.

If I remove the setTimeout, then the code works as it should, first finishing all of the .each commands and then alerting finished.  However, with the setTimeout, it alerts finished before it ever executes all of the .each commands.

I have the delay itself working perfectly, however the code AFTER the initial delay executes immediately, not waiting for all of the .each commands to execute.  Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'url to json data',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
            var time = 10;
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                document.write(val.term);
                   return;
                }, time); time += 10;
                });
            alert('finished');
            },
            error: function () {}
        })
```

How can I keep the delay while iterating through the .each commands and only when it is finished iterating through all of the .each commands, alert 'finished'?

Comment: "with the setTimeout, it alerts finished before it ever executes all of the .each commands".  Yes, that is what `setTimeout` does.  It runs the given function after X ms.  It is *asynchronous*.  The rest of your code runs, then the `setTimeout` runs some time later.

Comment: May I ask why you are using `document.write()`? This should rarely be used...

Comment: ... and why you want to use setTimeout in this particular use case in the first place?

Comment: document.write in this case will destroy your page.

Comment: The document.write was just as an example, I'm not actually using that.  There is code in place of where you see document.write, I was just trying to make the code I posted  here as small as possible while still getting the problem I'm experiencing across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use jQuery's deferreds here.  Use a promise, then call a callback when it's all done.

Untested, but you can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'url to json data',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        var time = 10,
            timeouts = [];
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            var def = new $.Deferred;
            timeouts.push(def);

            setTimeout(function() {
               console.log(val.term);
               def.resolve();
            }, time);
            time += 10;
        });

        $.when.apply($, timeouts).done(function(){
            alert('finished');
        });
    },
    error: function () {}
})
```

Comment: Wow...this works perfectly.  I appreciate it, thank you.  The things you made use of to make that work, I didn't even know existed...  I was able to incorporate what you provided into the actual code I'm using, and it works 100% perfectly.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the alert in a setTimeout too but reset it on each iteration so that it only runs when the `each` has successfully completed.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'url to json data',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        var time = 10;
        var t=setTimeout(function(){alert('finished');} , 20);
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            setTimeout(function() {
            //document.write(val.term);
              clearTimeout(t);
              t=setTimeout(function(){alert('finished');} , 20);
               return;
            }, time); time += 10;
            });
        },
        error: function () {}
    })
```

Comment: You're gonna need to `clearTimeout(t)` somewhere here.  Reassigning `t` won't clear the old timeout(s), they will still run.